# Change the border and icon positions on page direction

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, internationalization

I tried to change the position of the border on an input field and the input adornment of the search bar as well (search icon), but it didn't work. The code is on this link:

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Direction demo — Material UI</title>
    <!-- Fonts to support Material Design -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    />
    <!-- Icons to support Material Design -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`demo.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { Autocomplete, InputAdornment } from "@mui/material";
import { Search } from "@mui/icons-material";
import rtlPlugin from "stylis-plugin-rtl";
import { prefixer } from "stylis";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";

const theme = createTheme({
  direction: "rtl" // Both here and <body dir="rtl">
});
// Create rtl cache
const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: "muirtl",
  stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin]
});

export default function Direction() {
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div dir="rtl">
          <TextField label="Name" variant="standard" />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            style={{ borderLeft: "5px solid red" }}
          />
          <Autocomplete
            freeSolo
            options={[]}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                placeholder="Search"
                InputProps={{
                  endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment
                      position="end"
                      sx={{ position: "absolute", right: "15px" }}
                    >
                      <Search />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  )
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```

`index.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Demo from './demo';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <Demo />
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

[image: Edit falling-sky-pxcn8s]

It's using MUI.

Can someone look at it and tell me how to flip the border and the position of the search icon?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to move the search icon (use start adornment instead of end)

```
...
<TextField
  {...params}
  placeholder="Search"
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <Search />
      </InputAdornment>
    )
  }}
/>
```

to flip the border (I'm not sure what do u want exactly)
maybe use right instead left???

```
...
style={{ borderRight: "5px solid red" }}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.. i want to be able to basically 'flip' the border and the search icon dynamically when the locale changes (from ltr to rtl)